# Remap right shift to Down arrow key

Tags: 15.04

My laptop down arrow key just stopped working, so how can I remap the right shift key to work as the down arrow key?

Answer (score 0):

**xmodmap** is an utility for modifying keymaps and pointer button mappings. It usually comes preinstalled with Ubuntu.

> The xmodmap program is used to edit and display the  keyboard  modifier
>          map  and  keymap  table that are used by client applications to convert
>          event keycodes into keysyms.  It is usually run from the user's session
>          startup script to configure the keyboard according to personal tastes.

For mapping a key to another, we need keycode or key symbols for the keys to be mapped. This can be done with another tool **xev**. It also comes along with Ubuntu. Just run xev from a terminal and press the key and notice the keycode and key symbols logged in the console. For your case, It is

> state 0x11, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,state 0x10, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES

To remap the key bindings as you required,
Press Alt+F2 and enter the following command line `xmodmap -e "keycode 116 = Shift_R"`

Comment: xmodkey: command not found